# Puppet file dependencies with notify error configuring NGINX

Tags: nginx, debian, puppet

Configuring Nginx with a file" resource:

```
# We install NGINX
package { "nginx":
  ensure => installed
}

service { "nginx":
  require => Package["nginx"],
  ensure => running,
  enable => true
}

file { ["/var/www/html", "/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html"]:
  require => Package["nginx"],
  ensure  => absent,
  notify  => Service["nginx"]
}

file { "/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace":
  ensure => "file",
  content => file("nginx/aerospace"),
  notify => Service["nginx"]
}

file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/aerospace":
  require => File["/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace"],
  ensure => "link",
  target => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace",
  notify => Service["nginx"]
}
```

Results in an error:

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/aerospace]/ensure: created
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[nginx]: Failed to call refresh: Could not start Service[nginx]: Execution of '/usr/sbin/service nginx start' returned 1: Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[nginx]: Could not start Service[nginx]: Execution of '/usr/sbin/service nginx start' returned 1: Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
==> default: Wrapped exception:
==> default: Execution of '/usr/sbin/service nginx start' returned 1: Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Invoking the *systemctl* didn't provide much help to me either:

```
vagrant@debian-jessie:~$ systemctl status nginx.service                                                                          
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-12-10 14:34:59 GMT; 4min 53s ago
  Process: 6023 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6043 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3899 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
vagrant@debian-jessie:~$ journalctl -xn
No journal files were found
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something about Puppet or Debian here?

Comment: Seems like you have problem with config files because ExecStartPer call `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` for check it. Just call `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` under `sudo` from console. It should display all problem in config files.

Answer (score 1):

As maxd said, the error from systemd is that the `nginx -t` failed on your config file, suggesting that the config file has incorrect syntax. Run `nginx -t` and see what it says:

```
-t  Don’t run, just test the configuration file. NGINX checks configuration for correct syntax and then try to open files referred in configuration.
```

If you're managing the nginx config file with Puppet, you can actually add a `validate_cmd` to the file resource to run a check against it specifically, which prevents it from overwriting a file if the validation fails:

```
file { "/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace":
   ensure => "file",
   content => file("nginx/aerospace"),
   notify => Service["nginx"]
   validate_cmd => '/usr/bin/nginx -t',
}

file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/aerospace":
  require => File["/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace"],
  ensure => "link",
  target => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/aerospace",
  notify => Service["nginx"]
  validate_cmd => '/usr/bin/nginx -t',
}
```